# How do you restart a failed song?

Tags: rock-band-4

This seems very basic but I'm completely stumped.  When you're on tour and you fail a song, is there a way to restart the song? I've tried every button combination and the pause menu is no longer accessible either.

Whenever this happens, I only see the following options:

> - Next Song
> - No-Fail Mode
> - Quit Show

It currently seems the only way to do this is to hit pause right before you fail and restart that way, but this seems a little outrageous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There currently is no way to do this **after you fail the song when you are tour**.  You can restart, however, just before failing by hitting start and restart song.

Comment: Yeah, the simple answer is you can't.

Comment: I can confirm that you may only restart on tour before the song is failed.

Comment: Very disappointing. Thank you though for taking the time to answer!